# What mock object libraries are there available for D?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, d

I am just starting in with the D2 programming language. I love the fact that unit testing is part of the language itself but I can't seem to find any mock object libraries for it. Is there a standard one out there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only mock object library I know of is [DMocks](http://dsource.org/projects/dmocks/wiki/DMocks), but it is abandoned. It may not compile with recent compiler versions.
Maybe **BlackHole**, **WhiteHole** and **AutoImplement** from [std.typecons](http://digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_typecons.html) will help you to some extent.

Answer (score 3):

- [DMocks-revived](https://github.com/QAston/DMocks-revived) is a mock object framework for the D Programming Language, written also in D.
- [dunit (nomad)](https://github.com/nomad-software/dunit) Advanced unit testing toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not as fancy as a real mock object library could be, I currently do dependency injection with good results the following way:

```
class Car( Engine = AtomicEngine, Wheel = CartWheel )
{
    this()
    {
        engine = new Engine;
        ...
    }

    Engine engine;
    Wheel[4] wheels;
}
```

If no MockEngine is supplied Car defaults to using the preferred AtomicEngine which is neat because that's what I want most of the time. Also note that the injection is done at compile-time with no run-time penalty for the mocking capabilities, i.e. no inheritance is required.

```
unittest
{
    auto car = new Car!(MockBrokenEngine, MockWheel );
    car.start();
    assert(...);
}
```

Let's test the car with a broken engine like this.

Comment: That's all well and good but how do you create the mocks? That's what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of [DUnit](https://github.com/nomad-software/dunit) which contains a mocking solution. It's used like this:

```
class Foo
{
    // Mixin mocking behaviour.
    mixin Mockable!(Foo);
}

auto foo = Foo.getMock();
```

`foo` is now a mock.

The reference is here:
http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/nomad-software/dunit/master/docs/dunit/mockable.html

A bigger example is here:
https://github.com/nomad-software/dunit/blob/master/source/example.d